# how to call a 3rd party soap api and create an object of soapclient

Tags: magento2, third-party-library, soap-api

I am trying to call a 3rd party soap api and when i am creating an object for soapclient in my helper class its showing as class not found.

```
soapclient class.
class NTLMSoapClient extends SoapClient {
    function __doRequest($request, $location, $action, $version, $one_way = 0) {
        $headers = array(
        'Method: POST',
        'Connection: Keep-Alive',
        'User-Agent: PHP-SOAP-CURL',
        'Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8',
        'SOAPAction: "' . $action . '"',
        );
        $this->__last_request_headers = $headers;
        $ch = curl_init($location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_NTLM);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, USERNAME . ':' . PASSWORD);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        if(is_null($response)) {
            $logger->info('ERP class_soap: '.curl_error($ch), null, 'soap.log');
        }
        $response = preg_replace( '/^(\x00\x00\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\x00\x00|\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE|\xEF\xBB\xBF)/', "", $response );
        $errors = curl_error($ch);
        $details = curl_getinfo($ch);
        return $response;
    }
    function __getLastRequestHeaders() {
        return implode("\n", $this->__last_request_headers) . "\n";
    }
}
```

Am trying to create an object in helper class i.e. connect.php

```
<?php
namespace Curocarte\Erp\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\Module\Dir;


class Connect extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_moduleReader;

    protected $_helper;

    protected $_dir;

    // protected $_NTLMSoapClient;


    public function __construct(
    \Curocarte\Erp\Helper\Data $helper,
    // \Curocarte\Erp\lib\NTLMSoapClient $NTLMSoapClient,
    \Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader $moduleReader,
    \Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList $dir,
    \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Soap\ClientFactory $soapClientFactory,
    array $data = []

     ) {
       $this->_moduleReader = $moduleReader;
       $this->_helper = $helper;
       $this->_dir = $dir;
       // $this->_NTLMSoapClient=$NTLMSoapClient;
       $this->soapClientFactory = $soapClientFactory;
    }

    public function getConnection() {
        try{
            $path = $this->_moduleReader->getModuleDir('', 'Curocarte_Erp');
            include_once $path . '/lib/class_soap.php';
            // include_once $this->_dir->getRoot().'/library/class_soap.php'
            set_time_limit( 300 );
            $config = json_decode(file_get_contents($this->_dir->getRoot().'/config.json'), true);
            $erpIndex = array_search('erp_'.$config[0]['mode'], $this->_helper->customArrayColumn($config, 'option'));
            define('USERNAME', $config[$erpIndex]["username"]);
            define('PASSWORD', $config[$erpIndex]["password"]);
            stream_wrapper_unregister('http');
            stream_wrapper_register('http', 'NTLMStream') or die("Failed to register protocol");
            $faultString = "";
            $url = $config[$erpIndex]["url"];
            $client = new NTLMSoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
            // $client = $this->_NTLMSoapClient($url, array('trace' => 1, 'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE));
            return $client;
        }
        catch (SoapFault $fault) {
            $faultString = str_replace(chr(10), " ", $fault->faultstring);
            $faultString = str_replace(chr(13), " ", $faultString);
            $faultString = html_entity_decode($faultString);
        }
    }
 }
```

**NTLMSoapClient class is in class_soap.php which i have included**

when i run am getting the error as

> [2019-06-18 05:53:27] main.CRITICAL: Class
>   Curocarte\Erp\lib\NTLMSoapClient does not exist {"exception":"[object]
>   (ReflectionException(code: 0): Class
>   Curocarte\Erp\lib\NTLMSoapClient does not exist at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php:37,
>   ReflectionException(code: 0): Class
>   Curocarte\Erp\lib\NTLMSoapClient does not exist at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\vendor\magento\framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader.php:29)"}
>   []

Can anyone provide me some solution how am i supposed to overcome this issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

***There are some changes need at the code***

```
 new NTLMSoapClient
```

**need to change**

```
 new \NTLMSoapClient
```

I assume that `class_soap.php` location is `app/code/Curocarte/Erp/Helper` then code

`include_once $path . '/lib/class_soap.php';`

But if you `class_soap.php` location is magento project Dir lig folder then

`include_once $this->_dir->getRoot().'/library/class_soap.php'` is right code.

Comment: class_soap.php is a file in lib folder and am calling this lib file in my connect.php helper class. inside class_soap.php i have two classes i.e. NTLMStream and NTLMSoapClient. Its in app/code/Curocarte/Erp/lib .

Comment: am trying to send request to soap api using the following code

$client=$this->_connect->getConnection();
      if ($client) {
       $req->salesOrderDetails->SalesOrder = $SalesOrder;
       $resultRequest = $client->ImportSalesOrder($req);
       
      }

i am able print $SalesOrder data but in the above code am getting the error shown below

Warning: Creating default object from empty value in C:\xampp\htdocs\Magento\app\Code\Curocarte\Erp\Observer\OrderImport.php

Comment: Am not able to print the $SalesOrder data from the above code